# Is there a R function to quickly transform text into dates?

Tags: r, time

I am searching for a function in R, that quickly transforms text like "07/04/1995" into the date format in R.

Every help is appreciated!

Best regards
Jakob

Comment: You can choose one of `strptime`,`lubridate`,`anytime` or `zoo`. There are many questions on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `lubridate`, which has a set of functions that convert text to date based on the order of the month, day and year.

```
library(lubridate)
mdy("07/04/1995")
```

See the [cheat sheet](https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/lubridate.pdf) for more.